# Multi company, multi user, one platform

Tags: php

I developed a php application on with  all employees of a company with an account can login. I want to make this platform ready for multiple companies with their own employees. The challenge is that I want to have only one core, but a database for every company. Separate databases is more or less a must. Better for possible privacy problems, no extreme large tables, identical users can work at several companies, with same credentials.  And SSL of course.

The solution that I got working, is with multiple sub domains whereby every sub domain is in fact a domain pointer to the core domain with the program running. Because of this, a call to a sub domains, will be processed by the core domain, but the browsers url will keep showing the sub domain (company_1.application.com).    On the core domain, I check from which  sub domain the call is coming, and with that, select a database. Works great, but there is one disadvantage: SSL. The core domain has a SSL certificate. To get the sub domains working on SSL, I need to add every sub domain to the core domain SSL certificate. This is because the sub domains aren't domains with hosting, but just domain pointers. Because I expect that the platform will grow, creating an new certificate is giving me more and more room  for errors.

Therefore, I am looking for another way without the certificate problem. It must be something without a company selector on the login page, and "Keep me logged in" must also be possible. My not tested second idea. Add the company to the url like www.application.com/company_1. In htaccess I will reform this url to  www.application.com?index.php?comp=company_1. Then I can use comp value to determine which database to use . The problem is that comp won't be in every url, so I need to put com in a session variable. I think this will work, but it will break "keep me logged in".  When the user is not logged in, or session is gone, I must now which database to use.

Version two, SSL problem fixed, but new problem came up. Law conservation of misery?
Ideas, somebody, please?

Comment: Separate databases isn't a must. The term you want is "multi-tenant" architecture, and most big apps used one shared database - indexes and other proper database design make it work just fine. Your question is lengthy and hard to parse, but I suspect a wildcard SSL certificate would solve all your problems.

Comment: Why not use already existing systems that are specifically designed for this sort of thing? Like LDAP?

Comment: @ceejayoz
The application has company specific login pages for admin and customer section. Companies share people, that must have a login in more than one company section, but it must be possible to use same username/password.  looking to all these "need to haves", easiest way to achieve this, is with separate databases, I think.....
Wildcard SSL, didn't  know they exist. This will do the trick.

Comment: @Demi
LDAP, don't know this. I looked it up, but it is still not clear if this ticks all the boxes from the need to haves.